# execute Fabric functions in parallel and background on different hosts

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fabric

Similar questions were already asked but didn't solve my case.

I have something like:

```
from fabric.api import *
env.rolesdefs = {'server1' : [me@312312], 'server2' : [me@978978]}

@roles('server1')
def run_task1():
    do_stuff_forever

@roles('server2')
def run_task2():
    do_other_stuff_forever
```

Because the *_forever behaviour, I cannot run them serial. task2 on server2 would never start. How can I start them both in parallel on the two different servers? 
I tried:

```
def run_all():
    execute(run_task1)
    execute(run_task2)
```

The @parallel decorator didn't work. I tried the suggestions given here [fabric FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang). Having only screen available I could not find out how to start two screen sessions at the same time.
I thought, running the first in background could solve my problem? How would I put task1 in background reliably? Running fabric 1.4 and pytho n2.6

Thanks for the help.

PS: I want to avoid the obvious hack-around with a shell script running both task separately in bkg:

```
#! /bin/bash
fab run_task1 &
fab run_task2 &
```

Answer (score -1):

What if you set

```
env.parallel = True
```

Does this help?

Comment: Where would you add this? At the run_all() function ?

Comment: This results in: Fatal error: Needed to prompt for the target host connection string, but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode